# .is-invalid is rendered as .is-valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with react. I have a variable mobile which is supposed to be validated on each change in the input field.
here is the code for the component:

```
const EnterMobile = () => {
const mobile = useSelector(state => state.login.mobile)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
console.log('Mobile:', mobile)
return (
  <div className='container' >
    <div className={`form-group ${mobile.wasValidated ? 'was-validated' : '' }`} >
      <input className={`form-control ${mobile.wasValidated ? mobile.isValid ? 'is-valid' : 'is-invalid' : '' }`} placeholder='Enter your mobile number' value={mobile.value} onChange={ev => dispatch(updateMobile({value: ev.target.value}))} />
      <div className='invalid-feedback'>Please enter a valid mobile number</div>
    </div>
    <div className='form-group'>
      <button className='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the value in the mobile object:

```js
{
  value: "15", 
  isValid: false, 
  wasValidated: true
}
```

Here is the output that I get
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJDVn.png)

The element has .is-invalid class applied on it and yet it is being rendered as .is-valid

[Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBerq.png)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please include the snippet directly in your question, not as images of code.

Comment: maybe the css is wrong?
can you share a codesandbox

Comment: I suspect that @TomSlutsky is correct. In the inspection, it looks like the selector `.form-control.is-valid:focus` is grayed out (not active) but _the following one_, `.was-validated .form-control:valid:focus` is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why it show up as valid even though it's invalid?

In the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#how-it-works) on forms validation:

> As a fallback, `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes may be used instead of the pseudo-classes for server side validation. They do not require a `.was-validated` parent class.

So you could just remove the `was-validated` class and it would work.

```js
const formGroup = document.querySelector('.form-group');
const btn = document.querySelector('#toggle');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  formGroup.classList.toggle('was-validated');
});
```

```css
body { padding: 1rem; }
```

```html
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder='Enter your mobile number' />
    <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please enter a valid mobile number</div>
  </div>
</form>

<button id="toggle" type="button">Toggle was-validated class</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

## Recommandation

Use a React implementation of Bootstrap to avoid having to re-implement it yourself. There are a couple that are worth mentioning:

- [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)
- [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)
- [Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/) has a React implementation as well.

Even the [Create-React-App documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/) suggests the libs above when integrating Bootstrap to a React project:

> While you don’t have to use any specific library to integrate Bootstrap with React apps, it's often easier than trying to wrap the Bootstrap jQuery plugins. React Bootstrap is the most popular option that strives for complete parity with Bootstrap. reactstrap is also a good choice for projects looking for smaller builds at the expense of some features.

Comment: Removing the .was-validated class fixed the problem.